# Android Is there a programatic way to put app in sleep mode?

Tags: android

Can I put android app in sleep mode perhaps by issuing an Intent?  How exactly can this be done?

Comment: Define sleep mode. You want to put the device in sleep mode, i.e. turn the screen off and all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean putting the device to sleep mode, `PowerManager.goToSleep()` is probably what you're looking for.